# Unable to start the Weblogic Admin Server after DEV_OAM and DEV_OPSS DB Password Reset

Tags: oracle, weblogic, middleware, fusion

I have Reset the DEV_OAM and DEV_OPSS Passwords
Using the command

```
alter user dev_oam identified by Xxxxxxx 

alter user dev_opss identified by Xxxxxx
```

After the Password Reset i have tried to restart the Weblogic Admin Server and Oam managed server.When i am trying to restart the Admin Server, I encountered the below error.

> Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
>
> Error Code: 1017
>    Feb 20, 2015 10:58:08 PM oracle.security.jps.internal.credstore.ldap.LdapCredentialStore init
>       WARNING: Could not create credential store instance. Reason oracle.security.jps.service.policystore.PolicyStoreConnectivityException: JPS-10000: There was an internal error in the policy store.
>       JPS-01055: Could not create credential store instance. Reason oracle.security.jps.service.policystore.PolicyStoreConnectivityException: JPS-10000: There was an internal error in the policy store.
>       Error: Diagnostics data was not saved to the credential store.
>       Error: Validate operation has failed.
>       [oracle@oamps2 bin]$
>       [oracle@oamps2 bin]$ tail -f AdminServer.out
>       [EL Severe]: 2015-02-20 22:46:27.246--ServerSession(899981417)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.1.v20111018-r10243): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>       Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
>
> Error Code: 1017
>       Feb 20, 2015 10:46:27 PM oracle.security.jps.internal.credstore.ldap.LdapCredentialStore init
>       WARNING: Could not create credential store instance. Reason oracle.security.jps.service.policystore.PolicyStoreConnectivityException: JPS-10000: There was an internal error in the policy store.
>       JPS-01055: Could not create credential store instance. Reason oracle.security.jps.service.policystore.PolicyStoreConnectivityException: JPS-10000: There was an internal error in the policy store.
>       Error: Diagnostics data was not saved to the credential store.
>       Error: Validate operation has failed.
>       Need to do the security configuration first!

---

Can anyone suggest me what should i do to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

Have you altered all of your connection pool configuration passwords in weblogic to match the database password?  [This document](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=447674347081205&id=1545889.1&displayIndex=2&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=qse47m84v_81#REF) may help you, particularly the referenced documents at the bottom (You need an oracle support account to view these).